# My if statement only prints the last inputed String. How do I fix this?

Tags: java

My if statement has the same output.  This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    int y = 0;

    if (i == 0 || i == 10 || i == 20 || i == 30 || i == 40 || i == 50 || i == 60 || i == 70 || i == 80 || i == 90
                || i == 100 || i == 110 || i == 120 || i == 130 || i == 140 || i == 150 || i == 160 || i == 170
                || i == 180 || i == 190 || i == 200 || i == 210 || i == 220 || i == 230 || i == 240 || i == 250
                || i == 260 || i == 270 || i == 280 || i == 290 || i == 300 || i == 310 || i == 320 || i == 330
                || i == 340 || i == 350 || i == 360 || i == 370 || i == 380 || i == 390 || i == 400 || i == 410
                || i == 420 || i == 430 || i == 440 || i == 450 || i == 460 || i == 470 || i == 480 || i == 490
                || i == 500 || i == 510 || i == 520 || i == 530 || i == 540 || i == 550 || i == 560 || i == 570
                || i == 580 || i == 590 || i == 600) {
        u[y] = (String) c[y].getSelectedItem();
        read.println();
        read.print(u[y]);
        y = y + 10;

    } else {
        s = (String) c[i].getSelectedItem();
        read.print(s);
    }
```

Comment: You should look at that `if` statement and fix it. Then i'm sure it will fix itself

Comment: A slightly better approach to that if:  `if(i % 10 == 0 && (i >= 0 && i <= 600))`, if you really need all 600 values.  By the way, why do you have a variable `y`?

Comment: that y is for update

Comment: u[y] = (String) c[y].getSelectedItem();
        read.println();
        read.print(u[y]);
        y = y + 10;

Comment: @ßürgErSteäk - That is ineffective.  The way that you have written the code, `y` reverts to 0 at the start of the loop body; i.e. each time you go around the loop.

Comment: @ßürgErSteäk... Better not use y and just stick with x as from your code y just seems not needed. And also have a look at operators to avoid such complex conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `y` inside the loop so it keeps being reset. `i` will never be less than 0 and I assume that you want to have formatting regardless of the size of the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (i % 10 == 0)
       read.println();
    read.print(c[y].getSelectedItem());
}
```

You would be able to see what the problem is in your debugger by looking at the `y` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this is what you were trying to achieve:

```
for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if(i%10 == 0 && i>=0 && i<=600) {
        u[i] = (String) c[i].getSelectedItem();
        read.println();
        read.print(u[i]);
    } else {
        s = (String) c[i].getSelectedItem();
        read.print(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks much.......................